# How to make a splash screen with react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, splash-screen

I want to make a splash screen with react native, I try create this screen across this [guide](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae) but isn't work the splash screen it does not show me anything

Do you know another way to create this view, can you help me please.

Comment: I send you an Answer but you can search and find a splash with java and Manifest through the android studio source. (but they do same)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it's a solution to making nice **Splash Screen** with your style for `StatusBar` and **TimeOut** 2s to navigate it:

in my project I want to make a splash with **SplashScreen.js** and then navigate to **Home.js** or **Error.js** . my **App.js** navigate between the pages! Home.js & Error.js content are optional ( imagine only the `<Text>` HomePage & Error in it!

**SplashScreen :**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar , View , Text , ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
export default class SplashScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 , justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center' , backgroundColor : '#34495e'}}>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor="#2c3e50" barStyle="light-content"/> //NICE STYLE FOR YOUR STATUSBAR
                <Text style={{ color : 'white',fontSize : 18 }}>Hello Splash</Text>
                <ActivityIndicator color={'white'}/> //YOUR SPINNER WAITING
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

in your **App.js: **

```
import React from 'react';
import SplashScreen from './SplashScreen';
import Error from "./Error";
import Home from "./Home";

export default class Application extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.state = {
            view : <SplashScreen />
        };


        setTimeout(() => {
            //IF FALSE NAVIGATE TO ERROR
            if(true) {
                this.setState({
                    view : <Home/>
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    view : <Error/>
                })
            }
        }, 2000) //TIME OF WAITING


    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.view
        )
    }
}
```

If you build and test , your project run truly and Splash stay 2s in your screen then navigate to Home :)

Comment: Hi man, Thanks

I use your idea to create an splash, with a small modification, because I use react Navigation, I tell you how could I do it.


I create an intermediate class named Init, in this class I put  your code to display splash view

I new in react native, I am learning, you can tell me if this is the best way to do it using react Navigation.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
<FlatList
        data={[
          {
            id: "1",
            image: require("./someImage.png"),
            title: "Title",
            description: "Description",
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            image: require("./someImage.png"),
            title: "Title",
            description: "Description",
          },
          {
            id: "3",
            image: require("./someImage.png"),
            title: "Title",
            description: "Description",
          },
        ]}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <Item
              image={item.image}
              title={item.title}
              description={item.description}
            />
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
        pagingEnabled
        bounces={false}
      />
```

Where `<Item />` is the component that you'll show your data (image, title and description). This was created using React Native with Expo.